# Try-Catch or Result object for making rest requests?

Tags: c#

We have two versions of a wrapper method/class for making rest requests and converting them to objects in our project. This wrapper method handles various things like preventing us from going over limits among other things.

The first version uses a result object and never throws exceptions like so:

```
var result = JsonPost1<CustomObject>("/resource");

if(result.data != null)
{
    CustomObject obj = result.data;
    //Do logic with object here
}
else if(result.statusCode == HttpStatus.NotFound)
{
    //Handle issue.
}
```

The second one uses a custom exception instead and returns the object directly:

```
try
{
    CustomObject obj = JsonPost2("/resource");
    //Do logic with object here
}
catch(CustomNotFoundException e)
{
    // Handle issue
}
```

In at least 99% of requests the exception will not be hit. Which method is generally a better approach and why? Or is there a better approach than either of these?

Comment: JsonPost<T> is not throwing Exceptions?

Comment: @JeroenHeier The first one doesn't. They are both different methods. I guess I should make that clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO - Exceptions should only be used for exceptional things.
Do not use exceptions for things you can check in code.

However, this does not mean that your wrapper class should handle any possible response from the service - Only the common ones.
Ideally, if your service has a unified API (meaning all possible responses share at least some of their properties (like `Status` and `ErrorDescription`), you would want to handle that in your wrapper class. Anything that is used only in a specific type of response should be handled after you get the data from the wrapper class.

#### Update

[Microsoft's Best practices for exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/best-practices-for-exceptions#handle-common-conditions-without-throwing-exceptions) page states:

> The method to choose depends on how often you expect the event to occur.
>
> - Use exception handling if the event doesn't occur very often, that is, if the event is truly exceptional **and indicates an error** (such as an unexpected end-of-file). When you use exception handling, less code is executed in normal conditions.
> - Check for error conditions in code if the event happens routinely **and could be considered part of normal execution.** When you check for common error conditions, less code is executed because you avoid exceptions.

(emphasis mine)

This might be interpreted as the first option you've shown, if the fact that the data was not found is not considered an error (as the specific business logic dictates).

However, it might also be interpreted as the second option you've shown - since the catch clause will only be activated in 1% of the cases.

I still stand by my original answer, though. If the fact that the data was not found is not an error, it should be handled with a condition and not with a try...catch.

Comment: In the particular circumstance where these two methods for handling status codes diverged, we are performing a one-way sync. Either a user on the other platform has deleted the contact or an error occurred during sync and the relationship on our end is no longer valid.

Comment: We must handle the NotFound status code by deleting the relationship on our end and resyncing the contact. This is highly unlikely to occur and would be due to either a one in a milion error or a user misusing the system.

Comment: In best and most likely case, the exception would never get hit and there is no reason to return the status code, error message, and content of the request. In worst case, these all should be returned both for logging and to take corrective action.

Comment: So by using exception handling the goal was to both save processing power and memory(latency in garbage collection in concurrent requests) for the 99.99% requests made.

Comment: However, from a larger picture perspective perhaps the wrapper makes more sense given that some APIs might use status codes for flow control as opposed to exceptional circumstances. (Examples of rest APIs which function this way would be helpful)

Comment: I would probably use a status code based system, and exceptions for things like server did not respond in time (timeout exception) or stuff like this. See also [my answer to a similar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47451566/should-try-catch-be-avoided-for-known-cases/47451753#47451753)

Comment: "You should design your code for clarity, not performance", however, in my opinion based on the code examples posted above, the exception based model offers both greater clarity and performance. Would you not agree? Why?

Comment: Also from looking at code where we use the two variations of the wrapper class, it appears that the exception based model provides more clarity even in a more complex implementation. Internally, we have discussed this design and code clarity was the primary point given for not using exceptions. Upon review of the actual implementations it is hard to use that as an argument.

Comment: You do not have to agree with my answer. I gave an answer that fits the best on my knowledge. If you or your team members think otherwise, that's fine. Eventually, it's you guys that will need to work with this code, not some random stranger on the internet that seems to think otherwise.

Comment: No, I don't disagree, however, you haven't given any reason to agree. I'm looking for evidence and facts as opposed to conjecture or arbitrary opinion. Truthfully, I was hoping you would give me a reason which we were overlooking as to why the first option was the best.