# Should try-catch be avoided for known cases

Tags: c#, performance, if-statement, try-catch

I have a case which I know will happen but very scarce. For example in every 10 thousand times the code runs, this might happen once.

I can check for this case by a simple `if` but this `if` will run many times with no use.

On the other hand I can place the code in try-catch block and when that special case happens I do what is needed to recover.

The question is which one is better? I know that generally speaking try-catch should not be used for known cases because of the overhead issue and also the application logic should not rely on catch code, but running an if multiple times will have more performance issue. I have tested this using this small test code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Stopwatch sc = new Stopwatch();
    var list = new List<int>();
    var rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
    {
        list.Add(rnd.Next());
    }

    sc.Start();
    DoWithIf(list);
    sc.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"Done with IFs in {sc.ElapsedMilliseconds} milliseconds");
    sc.Restart();
    DoWithTryCatch(list);
    sc.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"Done with TRY-CATCH in {sc.ElapsedMilliseconds} milliseconds");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static int[] DoWithTryCatch(List<int> list)
{
    var res = new int[list.Count ];
    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            res[i] = list[i];
        }
        return res;
    }
    catch
    {
        return res;
    }
}

private static int[] DoWithIf(List<int> list)
{
    var res = new int[list.Count - 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        if (i < res.Length)
            res[i] = list[i];
    }
    return res;
}
```

This code simply copies a lot of numbers to an array with not enough size. In my machine checking array bounds each time takes around **210 milliseconds** to run while using try-catch that will hit catch once runs in around **190 milliseconds**.

Also if you think it depends on the case my case is that I get push notifications in an app and will check if I have the topic of the message. If not I will get and store the topic information for next messages. There are many messages in few topics.

Comment: So, you have answered your own question. Dont you?

Comment: @TobiasTheel You mean I should place login in catch? But isn't it against design patterns?

Comment: Atleast I would do it in your case. Don't know if that is against any design pattern.

Comment: A try-catch-construct won´t produce an overhread, only if there actually *is* an exception. So of course you should wrap your code into try-catch if there´s any chance for it to fail **and** if you can handle that in some decent way.

Comment: @HimBromBeere There certainly is exceptions I'm sure of that. The question is how many exceptions are needed for try-catch to be worst that if

Comment: From your description of real problem (with push notifications) I don't see where is exceptional case.

Comment: try-catch is for errorous situations, not for expected behaviour. So even *if* it might bring you some milli- or even less-seconds don´t do it, as it contradicts what exceptions are for.

Comment: Depends on what the error case is, you still have not specified it very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you have somehow missed the obvious optimization: if you worry that calling an `if` 100.000 times is too much... *don't*?

```
private static int[] DoWithIf(List<int> list)
{
    var res = new int[list.Count - 1];

    var bounds = Math.Min(res.Length, list.Count)

    for (int i = 0; i < bounds; i++)
    {        
        res[i] = list[i];
    }
    return res;
}
```

So I know this is only a test case, but the answer is: optimize if you need it and for what you need it. If you have something in a loop that's supposedly costly, then try to move it out of the loop. **Optimize based on logic**, not based on compiler constructs. If you are down to optimizing compiler constructs, you should not be coding in a managed and/or high level language anyway.

Comment: A great "think out of the box" approach. Thanks I will certainly consider this.

Comment: Good point! that's exactly what I mean in [my comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47451566/should-try-catch-be-avoided-for-known-cases/47451753#comment81859076_47451753). +1 from me as well

Answer (score 3):

So, it would be accurate to say that in your test, the `if` option was slower than the `try...catch` option by 20 milliseconds, for a loop of 100000000 times.
That translates to 20 / 100,000,000 - that's **0.0000002 milliseconds for each iteration**.

Do you really think that kind of nano-optimization is worth writing code that goes goes against proper design standards?

Exceptions are for exceptional cases, the things that you can't control or can't test in advance - for instance, when you are reading data from a database and the connection terminates in the middle - stuff like that.
Using exceptions for things that can be easily tested with simple code - well, that's just plain wrong.

If, for instance, you would have demonstrated a meaningful performance difference between these two options then perhaps you could justify using `try...catch` instead of `if` - but that's clearly not the case here.

So, to summarize - use `if`, not `try...catch`.

**You should design your code for clarity, not for performance.**
Write code that conveys the algorithm it is implementing in the clearest way possible.
Set performance goals and measure your code's performance against them.
If your code doesn't measure to your performance goals, Find the bottle necks and treat them.
Don't go wasting your time on nano-optimizations when you design the code.

Comment: "You should design your code for clarity, not for performance." If your answer had only this single sentence, it was worth 100 upvotes. But with the rest... 1000 votes :)

Comment: @HimBromBeere I'm glad you agree :-) However, I think that if my answer had only this one sentence, It would probably be downvoted until converted into a comment...

Comment: Yes the sentence "You should design your code for clarity, not for performance." is the essence of the answer I need. Let me see if more people agree with this stance or are there people who are willing to take the other approach.

Comment: Also about the example performance comparison, the operation is too simple to analyse like that. In real world every if statement will be a query to local SQLite database which is not that fast. I personally don't know but I think there is a valid argument that avoid overall slower application in favor of few long waits. Don't you think?

Comment: Well, You are the one that gave this test - I was under the assumption that it should be representing your actual case pretty good. If your condition takes 1 second to test, and you do it in a tight loop with a 1000 iterations, then you would have a better argument for using `try...catch` instead of `if`. However, a better approach would probably be to first get all the data you need from the database into your application's memory, thus saving the time it takes to query the database in each iteration.